# how to add a hyperlink to text in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, hyperlink

I have deployed my shiny app before. But there is one thing that I need to do is adding several hyperlinks in my app.

I mean somebody clicks the hyperlinks, and get some text information. If should I put the information into csv or xlsx file ?  Or just print them in shiny ui and server ?

**EDITE**

text:

****sample information**

GSE95401_EAE_Acute

Original publication title

Profiling the mouse brain endothelial transcriptome in health and disease models reveals a core blood-brain barrier dysfunction module
PMID    31611708

Data source https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE95401

Disease/Treatment

EAE was induced by injecting the MOG35–55 peptide containing emulsion.

Species          Mus musculus

Strain          C57BL/6-Rosa-tdTomato

Age              2-3 months

Organ   Spinal Cord

EC isolation method      fluorescence-activated cell sorting (FACS)

Treated group information     EAE Acute(Acute timepoints were taken on the first day that mice displayed a loss of 1 gram body weight.)

Treated group replication no.   3

Control group information   EAE control

Control group replication no.   3

Also,I know the hyperlink code:

```
tags$h6(tags$a(href="TEXT", "1. EAE (Acute)"))
```

But I don't know any other information about how to add text within hyperlink.

I hope somebody can help me. Vary thankful !

Comment: Try `tags$h6(tags$a(href="www.rstudio.com", title="1. EAE (Acute)"))`

Comment: I'm sorry about it。You may not understand what I said . I mean I know what you gave to me and I showed you above. What I need to do is I don't know how to add the text to  hyperlink just as the picture above.  Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are looking for.  Perhaps the code below might be of help.  Please replace the image names with some sample images you may have in your `www` folder.

```
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = div("TEST App", 
                              img(src = 'YBS.png',
                                  title = "A Test Application", height = "30px"),
                              style = "position: relative; margin:-3px 0px 0px 5px; display:right-align;"
  ), 
  titleWidth=300,
  tags$li(a(href = 'http://www.rstudio.com',
            icon("power-off"),
            title = "RStudio Home"),
          class = "dropdown"),
  tags$li(a(href = 'https://www.cnn.com',
            tags$img(src = 'YBS.png', height = "30px"),
            title = "CNN Home"),
          class = "dropdown")
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabBox(
           title = "Tab box",
           width = "100%",
           id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
           tabPanel("Tab 1",
                    tags$li(tags$a(href="http://www.rstudio.com", 
                                   paste("My Test on RSTudio link"),
                                   title="1. EAE (Acute)"))
           ),
           tabPanel("Tab 2",
                    tags$li(tags$a(href="http://www.rstudio.com", 
                                   img(src = "sphere.png", height="10%", width="10%", align="right"),
                                   title="2. EAE (Acute)"))
           )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks.Basically you're right. But I want to add text type content not the image type above. Can you show me detailly ?

Comment: Sorry . There is sth wrong. You showed me your method but the title in tab 1 doesn't appear. I want somebody click the title and he can see the text content of the image(but not image)  content above.  If I used the wrong method ?